# Need to create date in sequence

Tags: r

I would like to keep date variable in sequence so I am using below command and getting the following error.

Code:

```
dates <- seq.Date(vadu$date[1],vadu$date[length(vadu$date)],by="day")
```

Error:

```
seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: probably `vadu$date[length(vadu$date)] > vadu$date[1]`, you should check.

Comment: Are you sure `vadu$date` is a `Date` object? Please, provide the output of `dput(vadu$date)` (or a small subset of it, if it's too large).

Comment: dput(vadu$date)
structure(c(14831, 13901, 14546, 14366, 15208, 13866, 12939, 
13776, 13126, 13447, 14115, 13873, 14055, 13607, 14111, 14195, 
14778, 12257, 13375, 13835, 15294, 14549, 13942, 12503, 14927, 
13865, 14161, 13835, 15501, 13856, 14824, 14183, 14405, 14584, 
15538, 15113, 15025, 13127, 12826, 14054, 14393, 14393, 14131, 
14406, 15101, 14188, 14406, 15536, 14593, 14980, 12694, 14366, 
15324, NA, 14389, 15352, 12819, 14417, 14905, 14215, 12817, 13545, 
13906, 13748, 12442, 13727, 14892, 14189, 14903, 14315, 13068,

Comment: yes it is date object vadu$date
   [1] "2010-08-10"

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you encounter an error, trying debugging. Here, the error message is somewhat informative. It is coming from `seq.int`, which is a function called by `seq.Date`. If you look at the [the source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed415a8431b32e079100f50a846e4769aeb54d5a/src/library/base/R/seq.R#L69-L70) for that function, you'll see that the error is due your `to` date being less than your `from` date. Here's an example to reproduce the error:

```
seq.Date(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date() - 5, by = 'days')
# Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Check your dates and only try to create a positively ordered sequence of dates. An alternative is to specify `length.out` instead of `by`:

```
seq.Date(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date() - 5, length.out = 5)
# [1] "2015-04-02" "2015-03-31" "2015-03-30" "2015-03-29" "2015-03-28"
```

Comment: thanks! I got it your point but still trying to figure out where my date variables goes wrong because it run the before few months age and it should now run as nothing has changed in the date or dataset..